# Паттерн Репозиторий. C#. WinFroms

Tags: c#, winforms, шаблоны-проектирования

Не могу никак определиться как сделать нужную структуру программы, прошу помочь.
Есть программа, в которой будет реализован паттерн Репозиторий. Будет 2 модели. Среди прочего функционала, есть задача сделать CRUD операции для каждой из моделей.

И вот вопрос: для каждой CRUD операции есть отдельная форма. Сейчас получается так, что в каждом классе репозитория, где будут реализованы CRUD операции, должно быть инициализировано 4-е объекта каждой из форм и получается жесткая привязка. Можно ли как-то вместо создания 4-х объектов форм, сделать интерфейс и в нужно месте создавать нужный объект? И если можно, то приведите пример.

Comment: `в каждом классе репозитория, где будут реализованы CRUD операции, должно быть инициализировано 4-е объекта каждой из форм` вы что то мудрите с паттерном. Зачем репозиторию, который работает по сути только с источником даных, знать про ваши формы?

Comment: @tym32167, вот я поэтому и спрашиваю. Потому что не знаю как правильно разрулить связь форм и репозиториев, результаты работы которых,непосредственно, должны отражаться на форме.

Comment: ну с таким набором, я думаю форма должна знать о репозитории, репозиторий о форме знать не долджен. Форма должна использовать репозиторий для работы с данными.